LHP zero in voltage buffer compensated opamp
I am observing a LHP zero for the following miller compensated opamp with a unity gain buffer in the miller feedback loop. I am not intuitively being able to analyze the source of this zero. Would appreciate help regarding this. And can the zero be removed?

Are these ideal gm amps and buffer, or do they have frequency dependency?

they are not ideal. all mos based devices. so, they will have frequency dependency

do you suspect a parasitic coupling between the i/p and o/p of the buffer which introduces the zero?

If gm1 and gm2 are not ideal, could we have a little more information about them? Either implementation details, part numbers etc, and/or their frequency responses? Also, do you know the frequency of your LHP zero?

gm1 comes from the first stage of an opamp and gm2 comes from the 2nd stage. the voltage buffer is a simple CD nmos amplifier

What's the frequency of the zero?  Is there any resistance in series with the caps that could be the cause? (I.e. is attributable to the time constant between parasitic resistance and capacitance.)
